# How to convert a pdf to html in clean format?

Tags: html, pdf

Is there a website or a piece of software that can cleanly convert a PDF to a HTML document without a lot of HTML jibberish?

Comment: See https://github.com/fmalina/transcript

Answer (score 3):

The challenge here is that PDF is a layout language, not a semantic language, and the opposite is true for HTML.

This means that when transforming to HTML with any hope of remaining readable to the end user, you must force HTML to do the layout by positioning individual words (and sometimes letters), and the semantic structure is often garbled or lost-hence the gibberish.

You can get a sense of the problem by opening pretty much any PDF file representing a text document and attempting (by eye) to find words or paragraphs in the text.

Compare this to an HTML document, which is often straightforward to read from the source.

Comment: I tried to tackle this problem by formalising visual layout conventions to arrive to semantic HTML output. 1st step of the process is to translate to visual HTML using PDF2HTMLEx, than transcribe this to semantic HTML using transcript.py https://github.com/fmalina/transcript

Answer (score 0):

The HTML jibberish is generally caused by the PDF file itself, not the software used to convert it. You can use any number of packages to convert PDF to HTML. Some choices include [PDF Miner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html), [PDFTOHTML](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/), and I believe [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). Whether or not you will get any HTML jibberish isn't so clearly defined.